# Kendo Sortable / Integration - Grid - Not ordering after specific refresh

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-sortable, kendo-core

I have a Kendo Grid as per the code below

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ReportCompetencyViewModel>()
     .Name("listGrid")
     .BindTo(Model.ReportCompetency.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
         columns.Bound(c => c.Code).ClientHeaderTemplate("Code");
         columns.Bound(c => c.DisplayName).ClientHeaderTemplate("Description");
         columns.Bound(c => c.IEC).ClientHeaderTemplate("IEC");
         columns.Bound(c => c.Active)

             .ClientTemplate("#if(Active) {# <i class='fas fa-check'></i>  # } else {# <i class='fas fa-times'></i> #} #")
             .ClientHeaderTemplate("Active")
             .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-center" })
             .Width(100);

     })
     .Pageable(pageable => pageable
         .Refresh(true)
         .PageSizes(true)
         .ButtonCount(5))
     .Sortable()
     .Filterable()
     .Groupable()
     .NoRecords(n => n.Template("<p>There are no records to display.</p>"))
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
     .Selectable(selectable => selectable
         .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
         .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
     .Events(events => events
         .Change("lu.onChange")
     )
     .Pageable(p =>
     {
         p.PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 30, 50, 100 });
     })
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
         .Ajax()
         .Group(g => g.Add(x => x.IEC))
         .PageSize(50)
         .ServerOperation(false)
         .Read(r => r.Action("RefreshCompetenciesGridData", "ReportLookup").Data("lu.sendAntiForgery"))

     )
)
```

I have a partial that has a sortable element in it also as below.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Sortable()
          .For($"#{@Model.GridId}")
          .Filter("table > tbody > tr")
          .Cursor("move")
          .PlaceholderHandler("sg.placeholder")
          .ContainerSelector($"#{Model.GridId} tbody")
          .Events(events => events.Change("sg.onChange"))
)
```

The onchange event is

```
 onChange = (e: any) => {
        var grid: kendo.ui.Grid = $("#" + this.gridId).data("kendoGrid"),
            skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
            oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
            newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
            data = grid.dataSource.data(),
            dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));
        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

        console.log(newIndex);

        if (this.showSaveNotification && $("#" + this.warningDivId).length) {
            $("#" + this.warningDivId).slideDown();
            this.showSaveNotification = false;
        }
    }
```

The sortable element works great, the majority of the time.

When performing a re-order, opening a kendo window and performing a save action the grid is refreshed with the updated data in a TypeScript class as per code below.

```
save = (model: any) => {
var _self = this;

var girdOrderArray = new Array();

if ($("#grid-reorder-warning").length && $("#grid-reorder-warning").is(":visible")) {
    var grid = $("#" + this.girdName).data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItems = grid.dataItems() as any;
    $.each(dataItems,
        (idx: number, dataItem) => {
            var di = idx + 1;
            var id = dataItem.id === undefined ? dataItem.Id : dataItem.id; // Changing the display order appears to also change the dataItem from Id to id. 
            girdOrderArray.push({ Id: id, DisplayOrder: di });
        });

}

var da = new Tmsp.AjaxDataAccessLayer(Tmsp.Enums.AjaxCallType.Post,
    Tmsp.Enums.AjaxDataType.Json,
    this.saveUrl,
    JSON.stringify(model),
    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
    true, true);

da.ajaxCall(data => {

    _self.closeWindow();

    if ($("#grid-reorder-warning").is(":visible")) {
        grid.dataSource.read().then(() => {
            var dataItems = grid.dataItems();
            var arr = new Array() as any;
            $.each(dataItems,
                (idx, dataItem: any) => {
                    var id = dataItem.Id === null ? dataItem.id : dataItem.Id;
                    var gridOrderObj = jQuery.grep(girdOrderArray,
                        function (gridOrderObj: any) { return gridOrderObj.Id == id });
                    dataItem.set("DisplayOrder", gridOrderObj[0].DisplayOrder);
                });

            grid.dataSource.sort({ field: "DisplayOrder", dir: "Desc" });
        });

    } else {
        _self.refreshGrid();
    }

    return false;

}, (xhr, status, errorThrown) => {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(errorThrown);
});

return false;
}
```

This saves, and reorders teh grid accordingly by the DisplayOrder which is great and what I need. However, when I try and reorder anything else after this the reordered item gives me the new index, but isnt actually changed on the grid.

However, if I refresh the grid through other means, the re-oredering works perfectly.

So, my question, as I need to keep the display order as is prior the the save, how do I acheive this.

Things I have tried

- Updating the display order on the refreshed gird - suspected cause of the problem.
- Created a new controller that returns the partial and inisialises the control again -  No effect
- Resetting the uid (not a preferred option, but thought I would try and see if it was uid) specific. - No effect

Comment: Check the console, see if their are any errors. If so, can you copy and paste them here please.

Comment: @steadweb there are no erorrs in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha!!!

I have found the answer and Telerik do not make it easy to find how to do things.

using the link that I have here https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/interactivity/sortable/how-to/persist-order-in-localstorage I have been able to find the code that I need in order to persist the state.

I believe in one of my attempts last week that I was actually quite close, although not perfect.

this is how the on change event looks now

```
onChange = (e: any) => {
    var grid: kendo.ui.Grid = $("#" + this.gridId).data("kendoGrid"),
    skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
    oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
    newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
    data = grid.dataSource.data(),
    dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));
    grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
    grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

    console.log(newIndex);
    localStorage.setItem("sortableData", kendo.stringify(data)); //set the updated in local storage

 if (this.showSaveNotification && $("#" + this.warningDivId).length) {
        $("#" + this.warningDivId).slideDown();
        this.showSaveNotification = false;
    }
}
```

the new line in here is

`localStorage.setItem("sortableData", kendo.stringify(data)); //set the updated in local storage`

the new save and refresh gird looks like this

```
saveNewOrder = () => {

var model = new Array();
var grid: kendo.ui.Grid = $("#" + this.gridId).data("kendoGrid");
var _self = this;
var dataItems = grid.dataItems() as any;
$.each(dataItems,
    (idx : number, dataItem) => {
        var di = idx + 1;
        var id = dataItem.Id === null ? dataItem.id : dataItem.Id;
        model.push({ Id: id , DisplayOrder: di});
    });

var da = new AjaxDataAccessLayer(Tmsp.Enums.AjaxCallType.Put,
    Tmsp.Enums.AjaxDataType.Json,
    this.saveUrl,
    JSON.stringify(model),
    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
    true,
    true);

da.ajaxCall(data =>{

    _self.refreshGridOrder();

}, (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
    ////console.log(xhr);
    ////console.log(textStatus);
    ////console.log(errorThrown);
 });

}

refreshGridOrder = () => {
    var grid = $("#" + this.gridId).data("kendoGrid");


    grid.dataSource.read().then(() => {
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sortableData"));
        grid.dataSource.data(data);
        $("#" + this.warningDivId).slideUp();
        this.showSaveNotification = true;
 });
}
```

The other thing to remember is that as this is used from multiple locations is to also clear the local storage at the point of document ready.